# Смена классов у элементов массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js, классы

Есть массив, в каждом элементе есть значение name и onlain, я хотел реализовать так , что если onlain = false, у него будет класс member__item , в котором задний фон серый, а если onlain = true, то будет класс member__item-online, сделал проверку на то что тру или фолс стоит в переменной, и допустим у элементов которых стоит false к ним все равно применяется member__item-online ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
        items: [
          {name: 'Qwqeqweqw', onlain: false},
          {name: 'QWEasdas', onlain: true},
          {name: 'asdas', onlain: false},
          {name: 'qweqwe', onlain: false},
          {name: 'fasfaf', onlain: true},
          {name: 'asdasdasd', onlain: true},
          {name: 'qweqweqwe', onlain: false},
          {name: 'ASGsgsdfsa', onlain: true},
          {name: 'ZXvxvzxvx', onlain: false},
          {name: 'TJrtjrthr', onlain: true},
        ]
      }
   },
   methods: {
      OnlineClass() {
         if (this.items.onlain = true) {
            return 'member__item-online'
         }
         if (this.items.onlain = false) {
            return 'member__item'
         }
      }
   },
});
```

```css
.member__item-online {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(300.41deg, rgba(0, 152, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
} 
.member__item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div :class="OnlineClass()" v-for="item in items">
     <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это присвоение `=`, а это сравнение `==`, а это строгое сравнение с типами данных `===`! Вы в каждом вашем `if` присваиваете значение, а не сравниваете

Comment: При сравнении или строгом сравнение, у меня вовсе пропадают эти классы

Comment: Вам надо в функцию передавать значение item. в OnlineClass вы пытаетесь сравнить массив со значением )

Comment: @SwaD если я обращаюсь просто к this.onlain , то тоже не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переделываем HTML вот так: класс должен ведь назначаться на каждую позицию

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <div :class="OnlineClass(item.onlain)">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В функцию передаем значение (true/false) и сразу возвращаем результат

```
OnlineClass(check) {
  if (check) {
    return "member__item-online";
  }
  return "member__item";
},
```

Comment: Что-то не сильно могу понять , что я должен передать в функцию , все возможные варианты перебрал, то они все синие , то они все серые, нету такого , что синий присваивается только тему у кого тру(

Comment: Вы переделали ваш div ? В функцию надо передать `item.onlain`. Я тестировал тут: [https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-silence-3yksc6?file=/src/App.vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-silence-3yksc6?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Нашел ошибку, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто задавать класс динамически, вот так

```
:class="{'member__item-online': item.onlain, 'member__item': !item.onlain}"
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          name: 'Qwqeqweqw',
          onlain: false
        },
        {
          name: 'QWEasdas',
          onlain: true
        },
        {
          name: 'asdas',
          onlain: false
        },
        {
          name: 'qweqwe',
          onlain: false
        },
        {
          name: 'fasfaf',
          onlain: true
        },
        {
          name: 'asdasdasd',
          onlain: true
        },
        {
          name: 'qweqweqwe',
          onlain: false
        },
        {
          name: 'ASGsgsdfsa',
          onlain: true
        },
        {
          name: 'ZXvxvzxvx',
          onlain: false
        },
        {
          name: 'TJrtjrthr',
          onlain: true
        },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.member__item-online {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(300.41deg, rgba(0, 152, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.member__item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <div :class="{'member__item-online': item.onlain, 'member__item': !item.onlain}">{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```